# Is there a word that combines the meanings of insidious/pernicious obstinance?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Essentially wilful ignorance used in a tactical manner so as to bring about gradual, negative effect.

Comment: We need : 1) more context 2) some research 3) a sample sentence as required by the SWR tag. Please see the [Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)  on "How to ask a question". That said, this sounds like _Mokusatsu_...

Comment: I have an answer prepared, but first I would need some basic requirements satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cascabel that more context is needed to zero in on the right word, but maybe you're looking for this word:

**bloody-minded**

> Stubbornly contrary or obstructive : CANTANKEROUS

[Merriam-Webster]

> If you say that someone is being bloody-minded, you are showing that you disapprove of their behaviour because you think they are being deliberately difficult instead of being helpful.

*He had a reputation for being bloody-minded and difficult*.

[Collins Dictionary]